# Could a short pulse of higher frequency and a longer pulse of lower frequency transmit same energy?

Tags: energy, electromagnetic-radiation, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, frequency

Could a short pulse of higher frequency and a longer pulse of lower frequency  transmit same energy to a target-particle ?If we could analyze just one peak and one trough photons that have different wavelengths should they carry the same amount of energy=h?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, becaus the energy of a photon is $E=h\cdot \nu$ with $\nu$ being the frequency. So if you emit one photon of $E=h\cdot \nu_1$ in a first pulse and in a second pulse two photons of only half the frequency $E=h\cdot \nu_2$ ($\nu_1 = 2 \cdot \nu_2$), then you have emitted the same amount of energy. But the color of the two pulses would of course not be the same (that would be a problem if your experiment requires a particular frequency, e.g. because to excite anything or so...).